# Python 3 psutil 'module' object has no attribute '_pslinux'

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I have an Apache Web Server hosting a python/flask application using virtualenv. The core code works fine but I decided to add in some resource collection page to show server based cpu/mem/hd stats. In my apache logs I receive the following errors:-

```
File "/var/www/appname/app/views.py", line 8, in <module>
[Tue Apr 14 14:19:51.421337 2015] [:error] [pid 16745:tid      140420497671936] [remote 10.100.0.52:42298]     import psutil
[Tue Apr 14 14:19:51.421349 2015] [:error] [pid 16745:tid   140420497671936] [remote 10.100.0.52:42298]   File   "/im/.virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py",  line 90, in <module>
[Tue Apr 14 14:19:51.421369 2015] [:error] [pid 16745:tid 140420497671936] [remote 10.100.0.52:42298]     import psutil._pslinux as _psplatform
[Tue Apr 14 14:19:51.421392 2015] [:error] [pid 16745:tid 140420497671936] [remote 10.100.0.52:42298] AttributeError: 'module' object  has no attribute '_pslinux'
```

If I run the virtualenv on my own on the same server and import psutil it all works ok.

Can anyone explain to me why this error happens and how to resolve?

Comment: What are you using to run the app? uwsgi? gunicorn?

Comment: @nathancahill wsgi and apache

Comment: Are you sure mod_wsgi is even compiled for and using Python 3.4? You can't mix a virtualenv for one Python version with another Python version at runtime. Things like extension modules will fail for a start. Have seen this mistake made many times. Work out what Python runtime mod_wsgi is using. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library and http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton - I think you actually may be right. I will try this on our test env and report back. It is confusing how you can use packages from a venv.......and then use a different python bin at run time....

Comment: FWIW. Read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html Make sure you aren't using embedded mode and ensure you are using proper way of referring to virtual environment and not just the site-packages directory. You still need to sort out whether mod_wsgi is compiled for version you want to use.